# Is "tag" named for "touch and go"?

Tags: etymology

A [Facebook meme](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10155530835310423&set=a.10150543050750423.370848.643115422&type=3&theater) (with 146 thousand shares) asks:

> How old were you when you learned that the game TAG stands for "Touch and Go"
>
> I was today years old...

Is the etymology of the game [tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(game)) an acronym of "touch and go"?

Comment: @DevSolar: Please post answers rather than comments.

Comment: Any purported etymology from an acronym before about 1900 is highly suspect.

Comment: @chrylis Any purported etymology from an acronym after 1900 is nearly as suspect.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, the dividing line for acronym etymologies is World War II, when acronym-derived words started showing up all over the place in the US (and to a lesser extent British) militaries.

Comment: @Mark There's a horrific modern propensity to invent and circulate folk etymologies based on acronyms, well out of proportion to the handful of actual acronyms that have made it into general use.

Comment: Surely this should simply be on the English stackoverflow site?

Comment: I'll note that "touch and go" is a training maneuver used by aircraft pilots.  It consists of landing the aircraft on a runway and then immediately taking off again (allowing several practice landings to be undertaken in a short period of time).  No doubt this is abbreviated as "TAG" on flight plans and such.  This would be largely separate in etymology/origin from the child's game.

Comment: @Fattie This question as asked ("Is this meme correct?") probably fits better here, but I think a better question could be asked (and better answers given) on [english.se] for something like "What is the origin of the word _tag_?" Assuming it wouldn't violate cross-posting rules.

Comment: @Fattie: It isn't an either/or. It fits on both sites.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

No, but the association between "tag" and "touch and go" is more than 100 years old.

See the 1912 printing of the song [A GAME OF TAG](https://books.google.com/books?id=xzM5AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA34&dq=%22tag%22%20%22touch%20and%20go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUlIm0mqbcAhWQ0VMKHfahAt0Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22tag%22%20%22touch%20and%20go%22&f=false):

> playing tag, Touch and go

And in the 1902 [Music for the child world: Rhythms, marches and games](https://books.google.com/books?id=GG9ViRHcJ20C&pg=PA14&dq=%22tag%22%20%22touch%20and%20go%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjUlIm0mqbcAhWQ0VMKHfahAt0Q6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22tag%22%20%22touch%20and%20go%22&f=false) there is also the song "GAME OF TAG" (music only, no lyrics), with the note below the title "Touch and go.  Good for all kinds of running games. …"

Nonetheless, the February 1866 [American Agriculturist](https://books.google.com/books?id=zeBFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=%22game%20of%20tag%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizl47InabcAhWNy1MKHW_JCNcQ6AEIOTAD#v=onepage&q=%22game%20of%20tag%22&f=false), volume XXV, at page 67 says:

> Game of “Tag,” with variations
> Probably every boy and girl of ten years old knows how to play the old game of “tag.” It is so old that the children of the Roman empire used to play it thousands of years ago; the name “tag” comes from their language, tago, or tango, as it written in later times, meaning “I touch.”

Similarly, the 1848 [The pentamerone, or, The story of stories, translated by J.E. Taylor](https://books.google.com/books?id=vCwEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA402&dq=%22game%20of%20tag%22%20%22tago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8l5DBoKbcAhWBVt8KHd7IBlMQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=%22game%20of%20tag%22%20%22tago%22&f=false) says:

> … English game of 'Tag' (Touch, from the Latin *tango* or *tago*), in which one, who is called Tag, runs after and tries to touch the others ; when he succeeds he cries Tag, and the one touched becomes Tag in his turn

Also, the 1828 [Webster's Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=YRdFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT205&dq=%22Latin%20tango,%20to%20touch,%20which%20was%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX7cmzoqbcAhWiSt8KHe61DjAQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22Latin%20tango%2C%20to%20touch%2C%20which%20was%22&f=false) says:

> the original orthography of the Latin *tango*, to touch, which was *tago*.

Other dictionaries such as the [Century Dictionary](https://archive.org/stream/centurydictipt2100whituoft#page/6158/mode/2up) (1891) dispute the Latin origin theory, instead saying the origin is unknown.

In Drayton's 1622 [Poly-Olbion](https://books.google.com/books?id=cLdRAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA538&dq=%22Barley-break,%20at%20Tick,%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNppL5k6vcAhUOx1kKHZVlA0QQ6AEIKzAB#v=onepage&q=%22Barley-break%2C%20at%20Tick%2C%22&f=false), song 30, it is stated:

> Whereas the mountain nymphs, and those that do frequent
> The fountains, fields and groves, with wondrous merriment,
> By moonshine many a night, do give each other chase,
> At Hood-wink, Barley-break, at Tick, or prison-base

and in [Francis Willughby's Book of Games](https://books.google.com/books?id=qNnfAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=tick), written in the 1660s, it is stated:

> One boy touches another and cries, Tick. Hee that is touched runs after the other that touched him, to tick him againe, and then runs from him as soone as hee has touched him. Hee that is ticked, & cannot tick againe, is beaten.

So one theory, as explained in [The Lore of the Playground: One hundred years of children's games](https://books.google.com/books?id=HY9I1e21AJcC&pg=PA31&dq=tag%20tig%201721&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBrYeAkqvcAhWkwVkKHWAbCLsQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=tag%20tig%201721&f=false), is that "tick" was the original term for the game, and the names "tag" and "tig" derived therefrom.

The earliest reference to the game as "tag" is in the 4 February 1738 *The Craftsman*, reprinted the same month in [The Gentleman's Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZExGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=%22TAG%20was%20all%20the%20Play%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibtsTanqvcAhWqUt8KHRGpB4QQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22TAG%20was%20all%20the%20Play%22&f=false) (quoted below) as well as in [The London Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=BvwRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22TAG%20was%20all%20the%20Play%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibtsTanqvcAhWqUt8KHRGpB4QQ6AEILDAB#v=onepage&q=%22TAG%20was%20all%20the%20Play%22&f=false):

> A manuscript writen by a great Uncle of mine, who dy'd [soon after the Revolution](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/47224/what-date-does-a-1738-british-author-intend-by-soon-after-the-revolution) came lately into my hands. It is a sort of chronological animadversion upon the Plays and Pastimes of Children […]
>
> In Queen Mary's Reign, TAG was all the Play; where the Lad saves himself by touching of cold Iron – By this it was intended to shew the Severity of the Church of Rome; and that if People had once gone off to the Reformers, tho' they were willing to return to their old Idolatry, they must do it upon hard Terms – But in latter Times, this Play hath been alter'd amongst Children of Quality, by touching of Gold instead of Iron.

Comment: Hmm, the Oxford English Dictionary doesn't seem to buy this theory; it attests the name of the game to only 1738, and for etymology says only "origin obscure" (the origin of the much older use of the word for a bit of cloth is also listed as uncertain). Those sources claiming a Latin origin for the children's game sound like folk etymology, just like "touch and go", only of an earlier vintage.

Comment: @1006a I mostly agree, but the 1738 reference is reporting the contents of an older manuscript and says "In Queen Mary's Reign, TAG was all the Play; where the Lad saves himself by touching of cold Iron".  https://books.google.com/books?id=ZExGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=mary+reign+play+tag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXtsO8vqbcAhXQxFkKHaanCF8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=mary%20reign%20play%20tag&f=false  So it is at least as old as Queen Mary.  It also discusses the theory that "Queen Elizabeth herself invented the Play".

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/tag seems to be more plausible. Besides for this, I'd  argue OED should normally be considered definitive unless strong reason not to treat it as such

Comment: Note also that the Webster entry is factually ludicrous. _Tagō_ is **not** the “original orthography” of Latin _tangō_, for several reasons, primarily: 1) Latin did not have a fixed orthography at all; 2) _Tangō_ is a nasal-infix present tense formation, which is a pattern that was productive in late Proto-Indo-European, but had lost productivity even in Proto-Italic. There are hints of an earlier _s_-present (_taxō_), but it’s unattested; there is no evidence that _tagō_ was ever, in pre-Classical Latin, a valid form of the verb at all.

Comment: Webster’s claim (not quoted here) that _tag_ represents “the primitive [= Roman-era Latin] word retained by the common people” is also quite preposterous. The number of words that can be shown, or even posited, to have been carried down so unchanged since Roman times is vanishingly small, and _tag_ is certainly not among that number.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet This 1690 book says "Tango, de l'ancien tago".  https://books.google.com/books?id=WVUTAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA884&dq=%22Tango,+de+l'ancien+tago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwitkPajhqncAhWC11MKHczAABIQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22Tango%2C%20de%20l'ancien%20tago%22&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD It’s wrong. It also says that comes from θίγω/θιγγαίω, which is equally wrong—even if the two were cognates (they’re not, and there’s really no feasible way they could be), there’s no way the Latin would come from the Greek. Etymology from that long ago is generally not very reliable. If they hit upon the right origin of something, it was usually by chance.

Comment: As an aside, when I was a child in 1970's UK (North Midlands), we used the name 'Tick' for the playground game - it wasn't until I was much older and in the South of England that I heard it referred to as 'Tag'.

Answer (score 10):

Created an account just to answer this question.

Whilst 'tango' does indeed mean touch, I don't think this is the true origin.

It only takes 5 minutes to Google (and/or a knowledge of British 'tag' variants) to know that tag is sometimes called 'tig', although this isn't really in common use in the modern day.

Tig's origin is supposedly from the old English word 'tick' - to lightly touch.

The old English word tick derives from the Dutch word 'tik' or 'tikken' - to touch.

Following is under the headword "tick" in "Folk-etymology: A Dictionary of Verbal Corruptions Or Words Perverted in Form or Meaning, by False Derivation or Mistaken Analogy" (1882) [Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8AcYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA391&lpg=PA391&dq=%22probably+a+corruption+of+tig%22)

[image]

Comment: A 4 February 1738 source's author is explaining what his deceased great uncle's book says: that "tag" was played in Queen Mary and Queen Elizabeth's reigns. https://books.google.com/books?id=ZExGAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA80&dq=mary+reign+play+tag&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiXtsO8vqbcAhXQxFkKHaanCF8Q6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=mary%20reign%20play%20tag&f=false  What is the evidence that the spelling "tig" was used first?

Comment: This answer could be improved by being clearer about its sources (Google is not a source, though it may be a good way of finding sources). The text in the screenshot looks relevant, but it's not clear where it comes from, and who is saying the "probably".

Comment: @IMSoP the reference is the entry for "tick" in "Folk-etymology: A Dictionary of Verbal Corruptions Or Words Perverted in Form or Meaning, by False Derivation or Mistaken Analogy" (1882) https://books.google.com/books?id=8AcYAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA391&lpg=PA391&dq=%22probably+a+corruption+of+tig%22&source=bl&ots=lFLVrNeKcP&sig=ugpDUAzfp3Z_b6MWTaXe0yDsWe8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj63vXv3ajcAhXKT98KHTaCDZMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22probably%20a%20corruption%20of%20tig%22&f=false

Comment: Cuz, your reference is saying that "tick" ... "is probably a corruption of *tig*", but you are contradicting your reference and saying the opposite.

Comment: Apologies for the unclear source and lack of referencing. The source used was to demonstrate that in many parts of Britain, 'tag' is referred to as 'tig'. Mainly in northern parts of Britain. It then goes on to add the Latin and Dutch words for comparison.

Comment: And although it doesn't prove that 'tag' is a derivative of 'tig' in the first instance, you could ask just about any British person of a certain age of above and they'd confirm that tag, tig, and it are the same game.

Comment: Actually in (modern) Dutch the game is still called 'tikkertje'